# "Bundle identifier has not been setup correctly" ao exportar jogo para Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Estou fazendo um jogo 2D para Android (ainda aprendendo) com o Unity, mas tive problemas quando tentei exportar pra ver como ia ficar a tela inicial no Android. O Unity deu esse erro:

> Bundle identifier has not been setup correctly
>
> Please set the bundle identifier in the player settings
> 'com.YourCompanyName.YpurProductName'. The value must follow the convention and can contain alphanumeric characters and underscore. Each segment must not start with a numeric character or underscore.

Tentei resolver atualizando o SDK do Android pois pensava que arquivos estavam faltado, já que quando exporto para outras plataformas como Windows e Linux funciona perfeitamente, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estava procurando algo sobre esse erro e encontrei [um post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/162141/android-bundle-identifier-has-not-been-setup.html?sort=oldest) na comunidade da própria Unity. Resumindo o que está dito lá:

- Garanta que o seu *bundle identifier* seja válido (estrutura estilo nome de domínio, somente caracteres alfanuméricos, e nenhum nível pode começar com número).
- Defina o identificador nas configurações do player (`Edit > Project Settings > Player > Per-Platform Settings > Other Settings`).

Comment: obrigado, resolveu meu problema